# How can I always print 15 non-zero digits in Java?

Tags: java, printf, decimalformat

Say for example that I have the Double value `1.23456789123456`. I want to be able to multiply this number by various powers of 10 and display the output as

```
  123.456789123456
12345.6789123456
    0.0123456789123456
    0.000123456789123456
etc
```

Is there any way to do this in Java without having to use if...then statements to handle the changing decimal precision required for different powers of 10?

Comment: Yes, there are several. What have you tried?

Comment: Right now I am playing around with using log10 and DecimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits

Comment: it's impossible to always print 15 non-zero digits of a lots of numbers, e.g. 1 cannot be printed as 15 non-zero digits because the other digits are always zero

Comment: Good point. However, for what I am working on I will always have a full set of fractional values so I don't have to worry about trailing zeros. I am just trying to make sure I display the 15 significant digits without adding in garbage values.

Comment: there are many fractional values which have zero at its 15th digit, e.g. 1+ 23456789123450/99999999999999

Comment: i am just trying to find exception so that you can prevent possible bugs in your code

Comment: I appreciate that :) I would prefer to strip out trailing zeros, but could live with printing them. The primary thing I'm looking for is showing 0.000123456789123456 instead of 0.000123456789123. I guess that my title could have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be improved, but it's close:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(format(123.456789123456d));
        System.out.println(format(12345.6789123456d));
        System.out.println(format(0.0123456789123456d));
        System.out.println(format(0.000123456789123456d));
    }

    public static String format(final double d) {
        final int before = 16 - Integer.toString((int) d).length();
        final String format = "%" + (16 + before) + "." + before + "f";
        return String.format(format, d);
    }
```

Output:

```
        123.4567891234560
      12345.67891234560
          0.012345678912346
          0.000123456789123
```

Comment: With one little tweak, it works like a charm. Thanks!
final int before = 15 - (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(d));

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the number as an actual floating point value, try representing the number as a `String` without a decimal point (e.g., `"123456789123456"`). Then using the `String.substring()` method, you can print the decimal point wherever you want, include leading zeroes, etc. I don't know that you can totally avoid using any `if` statements, but the logic should be fairly straightforward.

For instance, this prints the decimal after three significant digits:

```
String n = "123456789123456";
System.out.print(n.substring(0, 3));
System.out.print('.');
System.out.print(n.substring(3));
```

Comment: you could always then use [Float.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) to get it back into float

Comment: @drone.ah - Assuming you know where you want to set the decimal point for the conversion. :)

Comment: @TedHopp - The numbers are stored as Double values and I am trying to "pretty print" them upon request. Double.toString() seems to "helpfully" (for my purposes anyway) output large / small numbers in scientific notation which would complicate this approach.